# The multiple target temperature control for TemperatureControl Trait

Tags: google-smart-home

The refrigerator has multiple compartments（eg：fridge room \freezer room）,but we can only control temperature for one chamber when used the "TemperatureControl Trait", So how do we choose the Trait to control the temperature of different compartments separately?

Answer (score 0):

Base on the current Smarthome framework I don't think it is possible to achieve exactly what you need. A workaround which coming up in my head is to add Mode trait for freezer room which allows you to name your mode and setting freely (of course you will lose the functionality to control the exact temperature).

Comment: Amazon Alexa provides Range control interface,This interface allows you to control multiple objects，so I wonder how Google can do that